# Do windows get loaded differently from 10.10 -> 10.11?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller, awakefromnib

We have a window we want to display, and in 10.11, it displays as we expect.

we set all the properties of the views within the window in `-windowDidLoad`, and when the window is displayed, these buttons have the right colors:

[image]

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
   [super windowDidLoad];

   LightTheme *lightTheme = [[LightTheme alloc] init];

   _cancelButton.backgroundColor = lightTheme.controlColor;
   _stopButton.backgroundColor = lightTheme.controlColor;
   _cancelButton.textColor = lightTheme.textColor;
   _stopButton.textColor = lightTheme.textColor;
}
```

But, with this same code in 10.10, the colors are set to the default values for this button subclass

[image]

What's interesting is that if you interact with the buttons, they immediately redraw and have the right white background

However, if we move the code to -awakeFromNib, it looks good on both OSs, as soon as the window is displayed

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   [super awakeFromNib];

   LightTheme *lightTheme = [[LightTheme alloc] init];

   _cancelButton.backgroundColor = lightTheme.controlColor;
   _stopButton.backgroundColor = lightTheme.controlColor;
   _cancelButton.textColor = lightTheme.textColor;
   _stopButton.textColor = lightTheme.textColor;
}
```

Did they change when the window is displayed from 10.10->10.11?
Or are we missing something else?

It seems like it used to be:

> -awakeFromNib -> Display Window

Now it looks like:

> -windowDidLoad -> Display Window

EDIT: Here is the how the `backgroundColor` property is used:
First, get a color depending on button state

```
-(NSColor*)effectiveBackgroundColor
{   
   NSColor *result = ([self isOn] && self.backgroundAlternateColor) ? self.backgroundAlternateColor : self.backgroundColor;

   if ( !self.enabled && result ) // if disabled, dim the background
      result = [result colorWithAlphaComponent:self.disabledOpacity];

   return result;
}
```

Then in the `-drawRect`, call this method:

```
-(void)drawBackground
{
   NSSize inset = [self buttonInset];

   NSRect bodyRect = self.bounds;
   bodyRect = NSInsetRect(bodyRect, inset.width, inset.height);

   NSBezierPath* buttonPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bodyRect xRadius:self.cornerRadius yRadius:self.cornerRadius];
   NSColor* effectiveBackgroundColor = [self effectiveBackgroundColor];

   if (effectiveBackgroundColor)
   {
      [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
      [[self effectiveBackgroundShadow] set];
      [effectiveBackgroundColor setFill];
      [buttonPath fill];
      [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

      if( [[self cell] isHighlighted] )
      {
         [[[NSColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:self.highlightOpacity] setFill];
         [buttonPath fill];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How does the `backgroundColor` property work for these custom buttons?

Comment: Added the pertinent code ^^